# Creating a C++ COM client for C# COM server

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, com

I have a C# `ComServerProject` that implements an out-of-proc COM server, and I've selected the option "Make assembly COM-visible" on server project's "Assembly Information" dialog. In the same solution I have a C++ `ComClientProject`  that should use the COM interface defined in `ComServerProject`. However, I don't know how to actually *use* the interface defined in the server in my C++ client.

All of the Google search results say that you should do `#import "ComServerProject.tlb"` to import the type library from the COM server. But there is no `.tlb` file created during the build! I also tried checking the "Register for COM interop" box on the Build tab of the server project properties, but it still didn't create a .tlb file. Plus, it required me to run VS elevated, which I would like to avoid.

How can I get VS2010 to actually create whatever files are necessary to have a usable COM server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Tlbexp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c%28VS.80%29.aspx) on the generated assembly to create the .tlb.

Something like:

```
tlbexp ComServerProject.dll /out:ComServerProject.tlb
```

Comment: Do I need an explicit post-build step for that, or can I somehow convince VS to do it for me?

Comment: I am not aware of any way of getting VS to call tlbexp without resorting to a post build step.

Comment: you can: in Visual Studio 2010, tick the "Register for COM interop" box under "Build" for the assembly.